# Cannot debug configd

Tags: network, macos

To debug `configd` it is suggested by man page to run it using

```
$ usr/libexec/configd -d
```

And you would kill it before launching it using `SIGTERM` otherwise it will launch again as follows:

```
$ sudo killall -SIGTERM configd
```

From [man page of configd](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/configd.8.html)

> ```
>  SIGNALS
>  configd was designed to run without any intervention but if you insist on sending a signal to the dae-mon daemon
>  mon then the following are available:
>
>  SIGHUP   This signal, typically used to tell a daemon to reload its configuration, is ignored (there is
>           no configuration).
>
>  SIGTERM  This signal initiates a "graceful" shutdown of the daemon.
> ```

Problem is that `SIGTERM` is not gracefully killing configd. It is restarting right back up. Do you guys know any solution?

I also tried killing `launchctl`

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.configd.plist
Password:
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.configd.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
```

Also tried to disable `system integrity protection` for testing but failed:

```
$ sudo csrutil disable
csrutil: failed to modify system integrity configuration. This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS.
```

My platform

```
$ sw_vers 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G1004
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn off SIP on a running macOS system. You need to boot into the Recovery partition and run the `csrutil` command. [This page at Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html) details the steps nicely.

> 1. Restart your Mac.
> 2. Before OS X starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.
> 3. From the Utilities menu, select Terminal. At the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return: `csrutil disable`
> 4. Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.
> 5. From the  menu, select Restart.

You can re-enable SIP by following the above steps, but using `csrutil enable` instead.

Comment: This is not really what i asked. This should be more of a comment.

Comment: You need to stop SIP before you can kill `launchctl`, which is something you need to do to keep troubleshooting.

Comment: I googled that error code and found the steps to disable SIP. But my question is there any other way without restarting it. Why is configd not getting killed gracefully.